# Bean not working on jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a JSP which uses Javascript to display the date on the page. The date was created that way :

```
<script language="Javascript">
    objDate = new Date();
    document.write(objDate.getDate());
</script>
```

But now I am trying to get the date from a Java Bean instead. However, the date is no more displayed and there is no log at all, despite the log.info I have put in the Java.

In my Jsp Page :

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
<%@page import="com.my.package.DateRenderer"%>
<jsp:useBean id="DateRenderer" scope="application" 
    class="com.my.package.DateRenderer"/>
...
    <script language="Javascript">
        //objDate = new Date(); //old way
        objDate = DateRenderer.getDayDate(); //new way
        document.write(objDate.getDate());
    </script>
```

In my Java Class, the method I am trying to call is static :

```
public class DateRenderer {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(DateRenderer.class);

    public DateRenderer(){
    }

    public static Date getDayDate(){
        log.info("New Date for test!");
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

It looks like the DateRenderer could not be resolved but did not display any Exception. Do I miss something ? I do not have a lot of experience in jsp.

Comment: You are mixing server and client code. DateRenderer is a server object of Java, objDate is a Javascript variable in the browser.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I have seen I can use `objDate <%=DateRenderer.getDayDate()%>;` to fetch variables from the server-side, and the server-side method hits indeed (logs for proof). However the page still does not display the date. Is it possible this is due to the fact that the page was already displayed when the javascript was called (and the page is not refreshed)?

Comment: try set value to `Hidden Input` field  
`<input type='hidden' id='id-date' value='<jsp:getProperty property="dayDate" name="DateRenderer"/>' >`  
then access it in JavaScript, using its id field

Comment: or try `alert("${variable}");`
or
`alert("<%=var%>");` in JavaScript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answers, thanks to the question's comments.

- **DateRenderer was not found** because it was server-side, and not client-side. Scriptlets can get the server-side variables (for some complicated reasons in this project, I could not use ELs).
- **DateRenderer.getDayDate() did not return anything** because I did not properly catch it.

Here was the solution :

```
<%@page import="com.my.package.DateRenderer"%>
[...]

<div id="somediv">
    <script language="Javascript">
        <%
        String dayDate = DateRenderer.getDayDate();
        %>
        document.write('<%=dayDate%>');
    </script>
</div>
```